# Has Francesca Marie Smith written any episodes of Hey Arnold?

Tags: united-states, celebrities, movies, art

Migrate to movies se if need be please.

It says in this reddit post [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/todayilearned/comments/bx9qo4/til_francesca_marie_smith_the_voice_of_helga_from/)

> TIL Francesca Marie Smith, the voice of Helga from Hey Arnold, actually started writing episodes of Hey Arnold when she was only 11 years old. She wrote a total of 10 episodes.

There's a link to the wikipedia page, but I couldn't see any indication that she was a writer for HA!. However, she is credited as doing such on [IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0808216/#writer). Any source for the IMDB thing?

Comment: IMDB has credits listings per episode.  I found her listed as a writer for S03E01, and with more clicking you could probably find the other 9.  If you don't believe IMDB, you could stream the episode itself (apparently on Amazon Prime and Hulu) and watch the end credits.

Comment: @NateEldredge is that for helga blabs it all and harold the butcher? i checked just now and was not able to find any mention of francesca marie smith except as voice of helga. where in credits is it please? thanks.

Comment: @NateEldredge if you mean The Aptitude Test and Oskar Gets a Job, then my version unfortunately doesn't have credits. however, i don't see any francesca marie smith listed as writer or anything on the fandom for any of the credits or trivia of the episode pages or her own fandom page.

Comment: Where is the notable claim? The Reddit post was upvoted by less than 350 people (which is a really low number for a subreddit as big as /r/todayilearned), it is now more than 18 months old (which is ancient given the throw-away nature of Reddit posts), and the information was removed from the referenced Wikipedia page [six months ago](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Francesca_Marie_Smith&diff=next&oldid=967138731). It seems that nobody _really_ ever cared about this piecelet of trivia.

Comment: @Schmuddi I did say 'Migrate to movies se if need be please.'

Comment: @NateEldredge By the way, I see you all over stackexchange. Nice. And of course thanks for helping me out on several sites!

Comment: I would posit that this question would be closed as off-topic there as well, with the reason of: Trivia questions that do not add to the understanding or appreciation of a movie/TV-show are off-topic; We're not trying to duplicate IMDB. Please try to explain why your question is relevant for understanding the work beyond banal minutiae.

Comment: @CGCampbell because IMDB does not necessarily have something credible from which to duplicate? but eh thanks anyhoo

Comment: @BCLC you've asked for this question to be moved to an exchange that I am familiar with. I'm simply explaining that I believe it would be closed there and why.

Answer (score 2):

The ten episodes listed in the [Internet Movie Database](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0808216/?ref_=ttfc_fc_wr7) under "Writer" are

- Dinner for Four/Phoebe Skips (1999) ... (story - segment "Phoebe Skips")
- Phoebe Takes the Fall/The Pig War (1998) ... (story - segment "Phoebe Takes the Fall")
- Helga Blabs It All/Harold the Butcher (1998) ... (story - segment "Helga Blabs It All")
- Arnold's Valentine (1997) ... (story - segment "Arnold's Valentine")
- Helga's Boyfriend/Crush on Teacher (1997) ... (story)
- Magic Show/24 Hours to Live (1996) ... (story - segment "Magic Show")
- Operation Ruthless/The Vacant Lot (1996) ... (story - segment "Operation Ruthless")
- 6th Grade Girls/The Baseball (1996) ... (story - segment "6th Grade Girls")
- Helga's Makeover/The Old Building (1996) ... (story - segment "Helga's Makeover")
- Arnold's Hat/Stoop Kid (1996) ... (story - segment "Arnold's Hat")

As Nate said, if you want more, you can consult the credits in the videos of these episodes.

Comment: show me a screenshot please of a single episode in this regard. i was not able to find for the 4 episodes i mentioned to nate

Comment: @BCLC The credits roll at the end of a film is not always complete, especially for 20 minute episodes where the time reserved for the roll is very short. To be "credited" sometimes means literally in the end credits roll. However, a writer not being credited would be unusual. If contributors are not credited, it's usually extras, camera men, and other technical positions. But, it wouldn't be the first time that a minor who contributed artistically in a significant way is not given their due.